# Are tables supported when displaying RTF files in Windows Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, rtf

I'm creating a Windows Installer setup file using Wix and the standard UI library. I've supplied my own RTF file for the license agreement, but tables are not displaying correctly. Are tables supported in this case, and if so, what do I need to do to get them to display?

Basically, the cell border is only being drawn around the first line of text in a cell, and text from the 2nd column is flowing into the the first column. Here's a picture:

[Badly formatted tables in RTF file displaying in Windows Installer http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/58fc5187b7.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/58fc5187b7.png)

Comment: Does write.exe shows the file OK?

Comment: You mean Wordpad? Yes it shows correctly there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Installer ScrollableText control doesn't support complex RTF, basically try to keep your RTF as simple as possible, always save in Wordpad and if it doesn't look like it's going to work.. it probably isn't.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://n2.nabble.com/Rich-Text-Field-in-dialog-td707936.html) discusses problems with RTF in installers, Bob Arnson recommends using WordPad to save the file. Apparently, that will create a simpler file which is more likely to display correctly.